# How to use move next function in prepare statment?

Tags: php, function

it shows error working with normal statement but when i am using prepare statement it is not working.

```
$Result->MoveNext();


MoveNext();// not working with prepare statement
```

Comment: Sharing some code will increase the chance that someone will be able to help you.

Comment: `MoveNext` is not a standard PHP function. It could help if you mentioned what library you are using as well.